# Parsing a yaml file using PyYaml?

Tags: python, parsing, search, yaml, pyyaml

I have a .yaml file with the following format inside:

```
  ament_tools:
    release:
      tags:
        release: release/ardent/{package}/{version}
      url: https://github.com/ros2-gbp/ament_tools-release.git
      version: 0.4.0-0
    source:
      type: git
      url: https://github.com/ament/ament_tools.git
      version: ardent
    status: maintained
  cartographer:
    release:
      tags:
        release: release/ardent/{package}/{version}
      url: https://github.com/ros2-gbp/cartographer-release.git
      version: 2.0.0-1
    source:
      type: git
      url: https://github.com/ros2/cartographer.git
      version: ardent
    status: maintained
```

I would like to retrieve the `url` information inside the `source`. So far the above example, I would like to retrieve the `https://github.com/ament/ament_tools.git` and `https://github.com/ros2/cartographer.git` URLs.

I have some code written below, but essentially, I would like to add the URLs I listed above in the `urls` list I have initialized. How do I specifically get to parse `source` and then `url`?

```
def get_urls(distribution):
    urls = list()
    tag1 = "source"
    tag2 = "url"
    
    # Open distribution.yaml file and collect urls in list
    for file in os.listdir("distribution/"):
        if file.startswith(distribution):
            dist_file = "distribution/" + file
            stream = open(dist_file, 'r')
            data = yaml.load(stream)
            

    print(urls)
    return urls
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the **get_urls()** to return the list of URLs as requested, else None.
I hope I helped.

```
def get_urls(distribution):
    urls = list()
    tag1 = "source"
    tag2 = "url"
    result_list = []
    # Open distribution.yaml file and collect urls in list
    try:
        for file in os.listdir("distribution/"):
            if file.startswith(distribution):
                dist_file = "distribution/" + file
                stream = open(dist_file, 'r')
                data = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    except:
        pass
    for elt in data:
        result_list.append(data[elt]['source']['url'])
    return result_list
    return None
```

**Output:**

```
['https://github.com/ament/ament_tools.git', 'https://github.com/ros2/cartographer.git']
```

Answer (score -1):

`yaml.load(stream)` will read the entire file and store it as a python data structure. You can then use list or dictionary operations to retrieve the urls. Essentially you can access by index or key, respectively.